# Why is this IIF function giving an #Error?

Tags: ms-access

One of my tables has a field named `Cost` and a field named `Extra Cost`. To come up with the `Total Cost`, I add them together with the following field, which works just fine:

```
Total Cost: (Val(nz([Cost],"")))/100 + (Val(nz([Extra Cost],"")))/100
```

(I divide by 100 because `Cost` and `Extra Cost` are stored without a decimal point)

Now it's possible that a record will have `Cost` = 0, and `Extra Cost` > 0. But if `Cost` = 0, I want `Total Cost` to also = 0. I came up with the following, but it results in `#Error` if `Cost` = 0. It works fine if `Cost` > 0:

```
Total Cost: IIf([Cost]>0,((Val(nz([Cost],"")))/100+(Val(nz([Extra Cost],""))))/100,0)
```

Basically I'm looking for:

```
If Cost = 0, Then Total Cost = 0
Else
If Cost > 0, Then Total Cost = Cost + Extra Cost
```

What is wrong with the 'true' portion?

Here's a few examples of the data:

```
Cost    Extra Cost
100     2.5
250     1.5
150     2.5
null    2.75
```

Comment: Can you change the data types of Cost and Extra Cost to numeric instead of text type?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your `IIf()` expression into an Access query and it seems to work fine there. Are you using that expression as the Control Source of a Form/Report control?

Comment: Both `Cost` and `Extra Cost` are stored as Text. I'm not able to change the type. (well, not with a lot of extra work)

Comment: Please show us a small set of sample values which throws `#Error` with your `IIf` expression.

Comment: I added a few examples of the data. Now that I look at it, could it be due to the `Cost` being a negative number, but stored as `text` type? I tried to convert the fields from `text` to `number` but get an error that there's not enough memory to do it.

Comment: Thanks.  When `Cost` is negative, what should `Total Cost` be?

Comment: Sorry, I gave incorrect examples. `Cost` is always a positive number. I updated my examples in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you can divide by 100 after you add the 2 values instead of dividing each of them by 100 before you add them.  That shouldn't affect the logic, but should give you a simpler `IIf` expression ... which will hopefully be easier to diagnose.

```sql
IIf
    (
        Val(Nz([Cost], "0")) > 0,
        (Val([Cost]) + Val(Nz([Extra Cost], "0"))) / 100,
        0
    )
```

Using your sample data in Access 2007, I get this result set from the following query:

```sql
Cost Extra Cost Total Cost
100  2.5             1.025
250  1.5             2.515
150  2.5             1.525
     2.75                0

SELECT
y.Cost,
y.[Extra Cost],
IIf
    (
        Val(Nz([Cost], "0")) > 0,
        (Val([Cost]) + Val(Nz([Extra Cost], "0"))) / 100,
        0
    ) AS [Total Cost]
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

If the issue is that `[Total Cost]` requires a text value, you can use `CStr()` to cast the `IIf` numerical value to string.

```sql
CStr(
    IIf
        (
            Val(Nz([Cost], "0")) > 0,
            (Val([Cost]) + Val(Nz([Extra Cost], "0"))) / 100,
            0
        )
    )
```

Comment: I tried your first example, but it only shows the `Extra Cost` even if `Cost` is >0. But, it didn't give the `#Error`. I'm trying the 2nd example now ...